# DB2 ROLLFORWARD option "TO END OF LOGS" - does it read archive logs?

Tags: backup, db2, transaction-log, logs, restore

I read about ROLLFORWARD option on link http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001978.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F3-6-2-4-106 but I could not find answer to my issue.

I have database in Archive mode.

I am using `DISK` option in `LOGARCHMETH1`

I made full ONLINE backup at Monday at 23:59

I have archive logs for Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday.
Let's say just for example one for each day: S0000001.LOG and S0000002.LOG and S0000003.LOG.

In Friday I have active log S0000004.LOG.

Let's say just for testing purpose I want to do the restore of Online backup made at Monday and all transactions committed during  Tuesday, Wednesday,Thursday and Friday. So I want to restore everything from Monday to Friday

I thought by reading all manuals that I just need to perform after restore `ROLLFORWARD TO END OF LOGS`

```
db2 rollforward db maxdb75 to end of logs and complete;
```

I thought that this command `to end of logs` it will include `Archive Logs(S0000001.LOG + S0000002.LOG + S0000003.LOG.)+Active Logs(S0000004.LOG)`

But one good database expert told me that: **"When rolling forward to end of logs without specifying overflow log path only active logs will be read"**

So I have 2 questions:

1. **What in my example will be restored in case of `"to end of logs"` command**
2. Is this the command if after the restore I want to rollforward everything from Monday To Friday in my exampe: `db2 rollforward db maxdb75 to end of logs and complete overflow log path "(/data/archiveLogsPath)";`

Thank you in advance!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whoever told you "When rolling forward to end of logs without specifying overflow log path only active logs will be read" was *wrong*.

When you have `LOGARCHMETH1` set to `DISK`, `TSM`, `USEREXIT` or `VENDOR`, the DB2 log manager EDU (`db2logmgr`) is responsible for moving log files to **and from** the archive location.  When performing a `ROLLFORWARD` operation, DB2 will determine which log files it needs, and `db2logmgr` will retrieve files for processing if they aren't already in the active log path.

Now, if you have `LOGARCHMETH1` set to `LOGRETAIN`, and you are manually moving log files from the active log path to somewhere else, only *then* will you have to specify `OVERFLOW LOG PATH` (or move/copy the transaction log files back to the active log path).

So: `to end of logs` means just what it sounds like:  DB2 will replay all transactions present in log files between the backup time and when the restore took place.

Comment: Hi Ian, sorry for asking you here this question but can you help me with this one issue that I am having on different issue? I know you are the db2 guru which may help me:) thanks  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154230/issue-with-one-query-can-some-index-help-to-make-it-faster

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Ian is correct here. I am sure your issue is resolve now. Also, archive logs can still exist in Active log path if we set LOGARCHMETH1 to LOGRETAIN  correctly . Details at [Information Center](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0008178.html?view=embed) can give better overview .Hope it helps !

Comment: What does your answer add to the existing, accepted one?

Comment: The link shared also states the different combination values of both parameters benefit the log management.